# How to visit a pair of elements in an array only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, algorithm, matrix

I'm programming physics for a small 2D game, and I need to check every object on the screen against every other object on the screen. That's `O(N^2)`, and I don't really like that.

What I had in mind:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++)
    for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j ++)
        if (collide(objects[i], objects[j])) doStuff(objects[i], objects[j]);
```

This is unnecessary, and I will check the same objects against one another multiple times. How can I avoid that? I thought of having a matrix, which would be `n*n` (given that n is the number of objects), and then each time I visit a pair of objects I would to this:

```
visited[i][j] = 1;
visited[j][i] = 1;
```

And then, I would always know which pair of objects I visited.

This would work, however, I would, again, need to set all of those cells, `n*n` times, just to set them all to `0` at start! Maybe, I could set everything to `[]`, but this still doesn't seem like a viable solution to me. Is there something better?

Obviously, my language of choice is Javascript, but I know C, C++ and Python relatively fluently, so you can answer in them (although Javascript, C and C++ have almost the same syntax).

Comment: If performance is an issue, you probably want to start using a quadtree.

Comment: I don't really think that it's necessary... There is usually <10 objects on the screen.

Comment: In that case, yes, it's not really worth the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't avoid O(n^2), but you can cut it down by half:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++)
    for (var j = i; j < objects.length; j ++)
        if (collide(objects[i], objects[j])) doStuff(objects[i], objects[j]);
```

Assuming collision is symmetric. If it's also reflexive, and testing for collision is expensive, you can move `doStuff(object[i], object[i])` out of the inner loop to avoid testing for collision and start the inner loop from `i+1`

Comment: Aha! Damn it, how didn't I think of that... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @souldcheck, also, what will I cut in half? n, or n*n? There's a big difference!

Comment: @Bane you'll have n*(n+1)/2 tests instead of n*n, so roughly half of n*n

Comment: That's cool, I guess. I'll go with `j = i + 1` to avoid checking objects against themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If your sprites have a maximum size, you could sort your arrays and skip comparing things that are vert+maxsize lower on the screen...